# Unable to run app on heroku using Flask and Shapely

Tags: python, heroku, flask, shapely

I have developed a small app which requires the Shapely python library. I installed it on windows via the .exe file so it automatically put the necessary DLL files (geos.dll , geos_c.dll) in Python27\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs.

When i tried to create a virtualenv on my box , i installed shapely via pip but it didnt put those DLL files and so i got this error:

```
from shapely.geos import lgeos
File "...\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 71, in <module>
_lgeos = CDLL("geos.dll")
File "C:\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

So i manually replaces those 2 DLL files in the virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs folder and it worked.

Now i am trying to deploy the app on heroku but again it failed because of the following error:

```
from shapely.geos import lgeos
_lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])
file "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 44, in     load_dll
from shapely.coords import required
file "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 47, in <module>
libname, fallbacks or []))
Error: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
```

So i assumed its crashing because of those 2 DLL files not being there. I copied those 2 files in a seperate folder and pushed them via git

I made a .profile file in my app root to copy those 2 files to the python environment

.profile

```
#Copy Shapely DLL Files to Site packages
cp -r $HOME/env_files/DLLs $HOME/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/
```

but still the app is crashing with the same error.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku use *nix system - it works with *.so type libraries *not* *.dll.

So delete any ENV vars and dll.

I install via pip

```
pip install shapely
```

install from [github](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely) failed